# Suggest nested data in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have some data in ElasticSearch:

```json
{
    "title": "example",
    "labels": [
        {
            "key": "region",
            "value": "us-la"
        },
        {
            "key": "url",
            "value": "www.google.com"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "title": "example",
    "labels": [
        {
            "key": "region",
            "value": "us-nyc"
        },
        {
            "key": "url",
            "value": "www.stackoverflow.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

ElasticSearch Mapping:

```json
{
    "properties": {
        "title": {
            "type": "text"
        },
        "labels": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
                "key": {
                    "type": "text"
                }
                "value": {
                    "type": "text"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I want suggest `labels.key`:

```
GET /my-index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "labels",
            "query": {
                "match": {
                    "labels.key": "us"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Response is:

```json
{
    "title": "example",
    "labels": [
        {
            "key": "region",
            "value": "us-la"
        },
        {
            "key": "url",
            "value": "www.google.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

It is retured in document, but I only want the `labels` field's matched object, like this:

```json
{
    "key": "region",
    "value": "us-la"
}
```

This will be convenient to limit response.

I tried `inner_hit`, but still not work.

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: provide your mapping/settings, please.

Comment: mapping has been provided

Answer (score 0):

I think you search in field "label.value" because the only field contains value "us-la".

I used the "inner_hits" and get the match.

```
GET /idx_test/_search?filter_path=hits.hits.inner_hits
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "labels",
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "labels.value": "us"
        }
      },
      "inner_hits": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Results:

```
{
  "hits": {
    "hits": [
      {
        "inner_hits": {
          "labels": {
            "hits": {
              "total": {
                "value": 1,
                "relation": "eq"
              },
              "max_score": 0.60996956,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "idx_test",
                  "_id": "VMefP4cB8815uFWkUuiJ",
                  "_nested": {
                    "field": "labels",
                    "offset": 0
                  },
                  "_score": 0.60996956,
                  "_source": {
                    "value": "us-la",
                    "key": "region"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "inner_hits": {
          "labels": {
            "hits": {
              "total": {
                "value": 1,
                "relation": "eq"
              },
              "max_score": 0.60996956,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "idx_test",
                  "_id": "VcefP4cB8815uFWkVui1",
                  "_nested": {
                    "field": "labels",
                    "offset": 0
                  },
                  "_score": 0.60996956,
                  "_source": {
                    "value": "us-nyc",
                    "key": "region"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my project, I use ElasticSearch to suggest some field's available value. `labels` is an Object field, now I want suggest its key (limit 10), but ES return some docs,  which `labels` field has many else keys. This will cause incorrect limit (10). How to resolve this?

Comment: the documents returned will be those that match the search term.  You use a list of labels, so it will always return the complete list.  Using inner-hits you will only have the document that matched but it seems that in your case it doesn't work.